# Couchbase REST Authorization

Tags: rest, couchbase, sha1

I am looking to access a local instance of Couchbase Server through its REST API. The HTTP GET requests are sent from Java.

The problem I am currently running into has to do with authorization.
Specifically, I have managed to use [Couchbase's Basic Authorization](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/exauthhttp.html), but only by obtaining the hashed credentials (bG9jYWw6dHdlZXRzOnBBc3Mx in the example linked to above) by monitoring a Couchbase browser session using Chrome's developer tools and inspecting the request headers.

Now, [another Couchbase article](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/security/security-pw-auth.html) mentions that Couchbase uses SHA-1 in compliance with SCRAM. However, no mention is made of how to obtain the 'salt' and 'iterations' parameters from Couchbase. Which, I assume I need to go from the credentials to the challenge solution (i.e. hashed string)

So, the question is as follows: how to get from the credentials (user="local:tweets", pass="pAss1") (from the example of the first link) to bG9jYWw6dHdlZXRzOnBBc3Mx?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Comment: Since you link to N1QL, by "its REST API" I believe you are referring to that service.

Comment: Its actually just base 64 encoded username:password, its not hashed at all. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

SCRAM SHA-1 support is only for the Data (K/V) service and only through [certain Couchbase SDKs which use the memcached binary protocol](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/security/security-pw-auth.html).  The Java SDK does have support for SCRAM SHA-1.

The REST interface you appear to be using is N1QL's API.  That does not support SCRAM SHA auth.

If you're looking to give some other application HTTP access, my recommendation would be to write a small Java app with Spring Boot or the like and use the Java SDK from there.  Then you have complete control over how auth is done at the REST interface.  A [colleague wrote one of these](https://github.com/ToddGreenstein/springboot-couchbaseAPI-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/DemoApplication.java) just the other day.  Note that even in this case, the Java SDK won't be using SCRAM when running N1QL queries, but you can use that as a point of control.

Comment: Note I also filed an issue to fix the doc clarity: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/DOC-2569